# After upgrade, raw sql queries return json fields as strings on postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am upgrading a Django app from 2.2.7 to 3.1.3.  The app uses Postgres 12 & psycopg2 2.8.6.

I followed the instructions and changed all my `django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField` references to `django.db.models.JSONField`, and made and ran the migrations.  This produced no changes to my schema (which is good.)

However, when I execute a raw query the data for those `jsonb` columns is returned as text, or converted to text, at some point.  I don't see this issue when querying the models directly using `Model.objects.get(...)`.

```
import os, django
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "big_old_project.settings")
django.setup()

with connection.cursor() as c:
    c.execute("select name, data from tbl where name=%s", ("rex",))
    print(c.description)
    for row in c.fetchall():
        for col in row:
            print(f"{type(col)} => {col!r}")

(Column(name='name', type_code=1043), Column(name='data', type_code=3802))
<class 'str'> => 'rex'
<class 'str'> => '{"toy": "bone"}'
```

[edit] Using a raw connection gives the expected results:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=db user=x password=z")
with conn.cursor() as c:
    ...
<class 'str'> => 'rex'
<class 'dict'> => {'toy': 'bone'}
```

Trying the old trick of "registering" the adapter doesn't work, and shouldn't be needed anyway.

```
import psycopg2.extras
psycopg2.extras.register_json(oid=3802, array_oid=3807, globally=True)
```

This app has a lot of history, so maybe something is stepping on psycopg2's toes?  I can't find anything so far, and have commented out everything that seems tangentially related.

Going through the release notes didn't help.  I do use other postgres fields so I can't delete all references to `contrib.postgres.fields` from my models.

Any ideas as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, same issue now with a fresh project and a single table.

Comment: Seems to be an issue introduced in django 3.1.1.  Using 3.1.0 resolves the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to @Andrew Backer's helpful answer, this is apparently intentional. From the [3.1.1 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1.1/#bugfixes):

> Fixed a `QuerySet.order_by()` crash on PostgreSQL when ordering and grouping by `JSONField` with a custom `decoder` ([#31956](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31956)). As a consequence, fetching a `JSONField` with raw SQL now returns a string instead of pre-loaded data. You will need to explicitly call `json.loads()` in such cases.

It's surprising to find an API-incompatible change as an aside in a bugfix release. For now I'll be adding `json.loads()` calls since, as already mentioned, there's no guarantee the `::json` workaround doesn't break as well!

Comment: above worked, but I have dozens of table with jsonfield , I have to add everywhere json.loads , seems too much work, is there any other solution to this problem? And I did not change my "django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField" references to "django.db.models.JSONField"

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so this seems to be a changed they introduced for some reason in django 3.1.1 to fix some other bug.  It de-registers the `jsonb` converter from the underlying connection, which IMO is terrible.

Django issues:  The first "fix" broke this basic functionality along with a denial of the use case of raw sql, the second is declaring the breakage invalid.

1. [QuerySet.order_by() chained with values() crashes on JSONField](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31956)
2. [TypeError loading data in JSONField if DB has native JSON support](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31973)

To fix this you can either make your own raw cursor, which django doesn't screw with, or cast your fields in the raw sql.  At least, that is, until they break that too!

```
SELECT 
    data::json,  -- db type is jsonb
    other_fields
FROM
    table
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this helpful post! My solution for this bug looks like this:

```
def call_database(query, vars=None):
    conn = connections['default'] #database name
    conn.ensure_connection()
    with conn.connection.cursor() as cursor:
        psycopg2.extras.register_default_jsonb(conn_or_curs=cursor)
        cursor.execute(query, vars)
        row = cursor.fetchall()
    return row
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sascha Rau, your post was really helpful. To possibly save others a bit of time I note that this is critical to the solution you propose:

```
conn = connections[settings.UX_DATABASE_NAME]
conn.ensure_connection()
```

Also, for this settings configuration for your Django project database:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {...}
}
```

you can refer to the connection to your default project database with `conn = connections['default']`

Comment: It is certainly not unique that "settings.UX_DATABASE_NAME" is a name in settings. e.g., UX_DATABASE_NAME = 'default'. I use it like DATABASES = {UX_DATABASE_NAME: {...}}, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

The previous solutions posted here were helpful for pointing me in the right direction, but in the end, my preferred solution came from a recent comment posted in one of the originally reported Django issues.
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31956#comment:18

This solution may be a bit hacky, but it avoids having to change and maintain workarounds in multiple places.

In `core/apps.py` file:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.db import models
import psycopg2

def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
    return value

# monkey patch Django JSONField for ORM jsonb results
models.JSONField.from_db_value = from_db_value


def _handle_jsonb(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = "core"
    verbose_name = "Core Config"

    def ready(self):
        # register empty decoder for raw sql jsonb results
        psycopg2.extras.register_default_jsonb = _handle_jsonb
```